# jquery .append() case sensitive element

Tags: jquery, append, case-sensitive

Hi I need to create xml from data in form to send it to webservice. The problem is that `.append()` is case insensitive, so `.append('<EDO />')` will create `<edo>`. But xml is case sensitive, so is there a way how to solve this? And I've chosen to use domObject instead of string, because this way I don't have to write endtags, what would be very difficult in my scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally as @Frédéric Hamidi said, to make case sensitive xml I used these functions:

`var domA = $.parseXML("<EDO_A />").documentElement;` to create element

`$(domA ).append($.parseXML('<EDO_Child />').documentElement);` to add child from string

`$(domA).append(domB)` or `domA.appendChild(domB)` to add child object

Answer (score 6):

Try using [$.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to create the XML element:

```
yourObject.append($.parseXML("<EDO />").documentElement);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, but irun to another problem. I have created element `var domA = $.parseXML("<EDO_A />").documentElement;` and there is no problem to add children like this `$(domA ).append($.parseXML('<EDO_Child />').documentElement);`  But when I have another object for examle `var domB = $.parseXML("<EDO_B />").documentElement;` I don't know how to add it to `domA` . I tried `$(domA ).append(domB);` or `$(domA ).append($.parseXML(serializer.serializeToString(domB);).documentElement);` where `serializer` is `var serializer = new XMLSerializer();` but it doesn't work

Comment: @david, what error message do you receive when you try `$(domA).append(domB)`?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake instead of `$.parseXML` i had only `$.` than the `domA` was bad object and it hadn't worked. Now `$(domA).append(domB)` works perfectly and I found out that `domA.appendChild(domB)` works too. The only question is what is faster

Comment: @david, `appendChild()` is probably faster because `append()` is implemented in terms of `appendChild()`. It never hurts to measure, though :)

Answer (score 4):

[`jQuery.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) will always create a new `DOMParse` and a new `Document`, so it is pretty heavy.

A better approach would be to use the (unintuitive) [`parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/), using the `context` paramter:

```
// Create the context XML document; doc and $doc is reusable
var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString( '<root/>', 'text/xml' ); 
var $doc = $( doc.documentElement )

// Create case-sensitive XML element;
// this will call doc.createElement( 'EDO' ), as of jQuery 2.1.3
$doc.append( $.parseHTML( '<EDO />', doc ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

```
$.parseHTML("<AddPerson>Adel</AddPerson>"); //result: <addperson>Adel</addperson>

$.parseXML("<AddPerson>Adel</AddPerson>"); //result: <AddPerson xmlns="">Adel</AddPerson>
```

I guess that you need these lines:

```
var request = $.parseXML(HtmlOrXmlStringSource);
$(request).find(someElementInside).append(HtmlOrXmlStringSource_2);

//Serialize XML
var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
request = oSerializer.serializeToString(request);
request = request.replace(new RegExp(' xmlns=""', "igm"), "");
```

Now the request is ready to be sent through $.ajax();

Thanks