# Knockout to keep XML node capitalization

Tags: javascript, xml, knockout.js

I'm currently using [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) to create some XML that's consumed by a third-party tool on the go.

Rather straight forward,

```
var queryString = "";
var query = [
    '<Values data-bind="foreach: items, attr: {\'data-bind\': false}">',
        '<Value data-bind="text: $data, attr: {\'data-bind\': false}"></Value>',
    '</Values>'
];
var queryTemplate = query.join("");
var tmpDiv = document.createElement("div");
tmpDiv.innerHTML = queryTemplate;
ko.applyBindings({
    field: field,
    items: items
}, tmpDiv);
queryString = tmpDiv.innerHTML;
```

However, to my great dismay, the output nodes are all lowercase:

```
<values>
    <value>1778</value>
</values>
```

In general web work the above isn't an issue, however the third-party tool is **capitalization sensitive**, so it's crucial for the nodes to be formatted as initially specified:

```
<Values>
    <Value>1778</Value>
</Values>
```

Is there something in Knockout's manual that I missed? Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: This is a jquery issue, not knockout: 

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719384/jquery-append-case-sensitive-element

Comment: @dperry I'm not using jQuery, but thanks for your input.

Comment: ah, yes, of course. still seems to be an html vs xml issue though.

Comment: @dperry Thanks a lot, your comments helped me get on the right track. _If_ using jQuery, one can simply `var tmpDiv = $.parseXML(queryTemplate);` and later bind to `tmpDiv.documentElement`. I'll get around to turning that back into vanilla Js soon enough. If you want to do that yourself instead, I'll happily answer yours as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As helpfully pointed out in the question comments by [dperry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2729683/dperry), this is indeed an HTML vs XML issue. Using [jQuery's `parseXML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) and binding to the 
resulting elements helps solve the issue easily:

```
var tmpDiv = $.parseXML(queryTemplate);
```

And then later simply bind to `tmpDiv.documentElement` and use its `innerHTML` instead.

If you're not using jQuery, you can resolve to simply using their implementation of the above function, might be outdated, original licensing applies:

```
// Cross-browser xml parsing
parseXML: function( data ) {
    var xml, tmp;
    if ( !data || typeof data !== "string" ) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
            tmp = new DOMParser();
            xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , "text/xml" );
        } else { // IE
            xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
            xml.async = "false";
            xml.loadXML( data );
        }
    } catch( e ) {
        xml = undefined;
    }
    if ( !xml || !xml.documentElement || xml.getElementsByTagName( "parsererror" ).length ) {
        jQuery.error( "Invalid XML: " + data );
    }
    return xml;
}
```